# Tendermint Networks,if some nodes are offline,is there any way to get the lost data for this nodes?

Tags: tendermint

Tendermint Networks,if some nodes are offline,is there any way to get  the lost data for this nodes?

Comment: the same data is stored on all nodes (transactions). why do mean by lost data?

Comment: I mean if  there are some data blocks added to the blockchain when some nodes is offline ,if the offline nodes are online again, can these nodes  get the offline data?

Comment: of course. when offline nodes become available again, they will request missing blocks automatically

Answer (score 0):

I am also currently exploring Tenderming and was wondering the same. As long as some of the nodes remain online a restarting node should be able to catch up. You can refer to this part of the documentation, available at:

https://tendermint.readthedocs.io/projects/tools/en/master/app-development.html

> When the app or tendermint restarts, they need to sync to a common height. When an ABCI connection is first established, Tendermint will call Info on the Query connection. The response should contain the LastBlockHeight and LastBlockAppHash - the former is the last block for which the app ran Commit successfully, the latter is the response from that Commit.
>
> Using this information, Tendermint will determine what needs to be replayed, if anything, against the app, to ensure both Tendermint and the app are synced to the latest block height.
>
> If the app returns a LastBlockHeight of 0, Tendermint will just replay all blocks.